# Ray-like shadow

Tags: html, css, svg

Is it possible in HTML5, CSS3 and (most likely) SVG to create a shadow like the blue precent icon throws?

[image: The effect I need is the shadow on the percent icon]

For example, a site content admin picks a picture for the icon (it can be a PNG with transparent border), and the markup with the rules give it a shadow like on the picture. The ideal variant would be a dynamic shadow that changes if we rotate or scale the icon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make the new long shadow trend with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083158/how-to-make-the-new-long-shadow-trend-with-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this effect by making several box/text shadows farther and farther away. Realistically, this would be very hard to code yourself, so you should probably use mixins or javascript. See this example: http://codepen.io/awesomephant/pen/mAxHz

Comment: Agree, bad of me - I just didn't come up with a proper name for the desired effect %). Thank you for the reply; I have already looked through the solutions, the mixin involving one seems the most appropriate